# Function defined but not used in C

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I have following code:

```
static __inline__ LIST list_List(POINTER P)
{
  return list_Cons(P,list_Nil());
 }
```

After compilation I got  following warning:

```
inlining is unlikely but function size may grow
```

I removed the  **inline** and changed into the following :

```
static  LIST list_List(POINTER P)
{
  return list_Cons(P,list_Nil());
 }
```

Now I get the following warning:

```
list_List is defined but not used.
```

I  didn't used to get above warning "function is defined but not used" before removing the 
**inline**. I got the warning only after I remove the **inline**. Actually the function is  used .When i comment the above function, i am getting  following  error:

```
 In function 
  (.text+0x148b): undefined reference to `list_List'
  In function `list_CopyWithElement':
```

Can anybody please suggest me how can remove that warning.

Comment: Is it jsut me - I see no difference in the two functions?

Comment: you haven't removed the inline in the code in your question

Comment: Is the function used?  If not, use it.

Comment: sorry, now the code has been edited. the compiler is gcc 4.1.2

Comment: @Stephen , actually that function is used. i tried with  commenting that function, it gave an error. The warning "function is defined but not used"  was not there before removing the __inline__.I got this warning only after removing the __inline__

Comment: Is list_List declared in the header file?  If so, it shouldn't be marked `static`

Comment: @stephen, it is not declared in header file.

Comment: @thetna, interesting - it must be declared somewhere, otherwise you'd get compile-time errors (undeclared) instead of link-time (undefined).

Answer (score 2):

"static" means that the function can only be used within the scope of the current compilation unit (source file, basically, unless you're doing weird things with #include).

Thus, the compiler is warning you that you have declared a function that cannot be used outside the current source file, but which is not (currently) used within that source file either.

Comment: In addition, when you told the compiler to inline the static function the compiler assumed that not using the function was not a problem because it is quite common for header files to have static inline functions that aren't used in every .c that includes them, but for a non-inline static this would be a little odd.

Comment: @nategoose, u mean the manipulation of makefile can help to remove those warnings?

Comment: @thetna: No.  I meant using the `inline` keyword made the compiler assume that the functions not being used was not a big deal.